# How to turn off mPdf generates text "in PDF format" in the resulting PDF file

Tags: mpdf

I am trying to learn and use mPDF version 7.1.0 and when it generates a PDF file it put a text like "...: in PDF format" on the top of the PDF file.

Is it possible to turn that off?

Thanks

Comment: Got a sample/screenshot showing this issue? Also, what code did you use to generate the document?

Comment: I can't figure out how to show a screenshot but here is the code.
My guess is something to do with the header but not sure.
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
        $mpdf->WriteHTML("my content"]);
        $mpdf->Output($file, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);

Comment: When running the sample code provided mPDF correctly generates a single-page PDF with the text `My Content` showing. No other text is included.

Comment: When I use TCPDF I have to turn off header and footer so I wonder how to do that with mPDF but can't seem to find any relevant info.  Do you know how to do that?  Thanks

Comment: There is no header or footer on by default in Mpdf.

Comment: How about a title?  Is there a way to turn off a title on the PDF output file?  Thanks

Comment: I just confirm the text that I got in the generated PDF file is from the title of the HTML page that I used to generate the PDF file.  Is there a way to turn that off?  Thanks